# submitList() in recyclerview with diffutil causes recyclerview to blink

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, listadapter, android-diffutils

I have a recyclerview that's been updated from remote source ,so it is working pretty well , the only annoying thing is that when the screen is pulled for a refresh and a get request is triggered the recyclerview is updated even though nothing has changed in the adapter causing the screen to blinks and that's annoying.

i tried messing with the diffutils but no result achieved

in my main fragment:

```
viewModel.fetchTopHeadline()
```

followed by an observer

```
 topHeadline.observe(this@FeedFragment, Observer {
        if(it == null) return@Observer

        topHeadlineAdapter.submitList(it)

    })
```

my Adapter:

```
class TopHeadlineAdapter:ListAdapter
```

and finally my diffutilCallback class :

```
class TopHeadlineDiffCallback :DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Article>(){
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

}
```

Comment: What does the `Article` class look like? Does it override the `equals()` method?

Comment: just a simple data class,@Entity(tableName = "TopHeadline",indices = [Index(value = ["publishedAt"], unique = true)])
data class Article(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int? = null,
    val author: String?,
    val content: String?,
    val description: String?,
    val publishedAt: String?,
    @Embedded(prefix="source_")
    val source: Source,
    val title: String?,
    val url: String?,
    val urlToImage: String?
)

Comment: If the `RecyclerView` is animating then it means that the adapter thinks that the items changed. Make sure that the objects have the same ids and exact same content

Comment: you are right, i am handling my data from local db after downloading from remote, so it turns out id has changed, and that's caused new item id not equal to old item id